# Epson TM-U295 in page mode won't stop feeding

Tags: printing, point-of-sale, epson, pos, escpos

I am trying to print in page mode on the Epson TM-U295 slip printer:

```
ESC "@"     ; Initialize
ESC "q"     ; Release
ESC "K" 31  ; Reverse feed 0.82in
ESC "L"     ; Select page mode
ESC "T" 3   ; Select top-to-bottom direction
"7/26/2019"
FF          ; Print and return to standard mode
ESC "F" 1   ; Set reverse eject
FF          ; Eject slip
ESC "q"     ; Release
```

The problem is that after printing the date, the printer just keeps feeding the paper. I have to turn it off to make it stop.

Is there a mistake in my command stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just set the page mode and the print direction, and have not set the page mode print area.

In that case, the default for the area of the TM-U295 printer is the maximum value from 0x0 to 210x480.

Even if only one line of date is written, if printing is started, paper feeding is performed to print all 480 vertical areas.

If you want to feed by the number of lines to print, after setting the page mode, you need to set the page mode print area of only the necessary minimum size before sending the print string.

The corresponding page is in Japanese.
[ESC W xL xH yL yH dxL dxH dyL dyH](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos_ja/index.php?content_id=56)